# ES2015 module import polluting global namespace

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have recently rewritten a bunch of old JS to ES2015 making use of module import/exports. I'm using Rollup and Babel to transpile this back.

The libraries are integrated into a number of other sites I don't have control of so I need to be cautious with code to make sure I don't pollute global, doesn't throw errors, etc.

**gulpfile.js**

```
var rollupBabel = rollupPluginBabel({
  babelrc: false,
  presets: [
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup"
  ]
});

merged.add(rollup({
  entry: './js/bnr.js',
  format: "es",
  plugins: [
    rollupBabel
  ]
})
.pipe(source('bnr.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('./compiled/js/')));
```

**bnr.js**

```
import * as helpers from "../lib/helpers";
import moment from "../../node_modules/moment/src/moment";

class Connect {

  constructor(window, document) {
    this.init();
  }

  init()
  {
    // Stuff happens here
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
// Helpers and what not here

var hookCallback;

function hooks() {
    return hookCallback.apply(null, arguments);
}

// This is done to register the method called with moment()
// without creating circular dependencies.
function setHookCallback(callback) {
    hookCallback = callback;
}

function isArray(input) {
    return input instanceof Array || Object.prototype.toString.call(input) === '[object Array]';
}

// The rest of moment.js
```

As you can see all the moment.js related code is being output without an closure/wrapper to keep it out of global. As a result I'm getting various errors on consuming sites.

How can I import moment.js or reconfigure the gulp task to import moment without polluting the global namespace?

Thanks

Comment: That looks like a commonsjs module or something with implied module scope - they're not meant to be global variables. Try using UMD as output format.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Bergi the format was the issue, switching to `iife` wraps the whole thing in a closure to solve the problem.